# git p4 clone has no files

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I'm migrating from Perforce to git, and in the process I'm trying to get the file structure right.

The current perforce structure is something like this:

```
//depot
    /android
        /main
        /other_branches
        /core_library
            /main
            /other_branches
```

and I'm shooting for something like this in git:

```
/android
/core_library
```

I set up my client spec View as follows (I'll worry about the branches later):

```
//depot/android/main/... //p4-git/android/...
//depot/android/core_library/main/... //p4-git/core_library/...
```

Wen I run the following, the full commit history appears, but no files.

```
set P4CLIENT=p4-git
git p4 clone --use-client-spec //p4-git/@all
```

Comment: It might be useful if you could include your client spec in the question.

Comment: Also if I `git p4 clone //depot/android/main@all` everything shows up as expected, just not with the file structure I want.

Comment: Same. For me it's as though `--use-client-spec` is not used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
git p4 clone --use-client-spec //p4-git/@all
```

Here you're passing a client path (`//p4-git`), but git-p4 expects a depot path. This causes problems later on when it tries to map Perforce depot paths to Git paths. Try running

```
git p4 clone --use-client-spec //depot/android/main/@all
```

instead.

Bear in mind that if you specify `--use-client-spec`, git-p4 will automatically use your client spec, whichever one that is. It will also remember this choice and use it for future git-p4 commands. It's probably a good idea to:

- create a dedicated client for git-p4 work
- make sure `P4CLIENT` is set to this client whenever you use git-p4
- avoid changing the view of your git-p4 client