# git-p4 clone from remote Perforce repo gives me empty folder

Tags: windows, git, clone, perforce

I'm cloning a Perforce project from server on Windows. I have a working Perforce client spec called `myclient`.

I used the following command to clone:

```
git p4 clone --use-client-spec //myclient/path/to/folder@all
```

The result is an empty folder `d:/local/path/to/folder`. `local` is where I choose to save my git-p4 local repo.

The output looks like these:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in d:/local/path/to/folder/.git/
Importing from //myclient/path/to/folder@all into folder
Import destination: refs/remotes/p4/master

Importing revision xxxxxx (0%)Ignoring revision xxxxxx as it would produce an empty commit.
Importing revision yyyyyy (31%)Ignoring revision yyyyyy as it would produce an empty commit.
....
....

Not checking out any branch, use "git checkout -q -b master <branch>"
```

The said client workspace works fine with P4V and p4.
What am I missing here?

I referred to this post which didn't help: [git p4 clone has no files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420612/git-p4-clone-has-no-files)

**UPDATE**

I followed @SamStafford 's suggestion and ran:

```
$ git p4 clone --use-client-spec //myclient/path/to/folder/...
```

This still gives me the empty folder:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in //myclient/path/to/folder/.git/
Importing from //myclient/path/to/folder/... into folder
Doing initial import of //myclient/path/to/folder/ from revision #head into refs/remotes/p4/master
Ignoring revision 474364 as it would produce an empty commit.
Not checking out any branch, use "git checkout -q -b master <branch>"
```

More tips needed.

Comment: What does `p4 files //myclient/path/to/folder@all` get you?

Comment: @SamStafford it gives me : Invalid changelist/client/label/date '@all'.

Comment: That's probably why attempting to import from that label doesn't get you anything.  I'm not at all familiar with git-p4 but assume you're supposed to be passing a valid Perforce path into it.  Maybe try `//myclient/path/to/folder/...`?